# Embedding MetaPost in LaTeX document

Tags: graphics, metapost, emp

I have problem using [the emp package](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/emp) in TeXlive 2010. When I try to use it with `empcmds` it prints contents to output. If I use `emp` it parser fails after first character.

Also - how should I import libraries such as MetaUML.

**Edit**: Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{emp}
\author{Maciej~M.~Piechotka}
\title{MetaUML}
\begin{document}

\begin{emp}
input metauml;

beginfig(1);
Class.A("Point")
       ("+x: int",
        "+y: int") ();

Class.B("Circle")
       ("radius: int")
       ("+getRadius(): int",
        "+setRadius(r: int):void");

topToBottom(45)(A, B);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(aggregationUni)(A, B)
endfig;

end;

\end{emp}

\end{document}
```

and error:

```
! Use of \emp@ doesn't match its definition.
<recently read> i

l.10 i
      nput metauml;
```

**Final result:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{emp}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\author{Maciej~M.~Piechotka}
\title{MetaUML}
\begin{document}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\begin{empfile}
\begin{empcmds}
input metauml;
\end{empcmds}

Hi there:
\begin{emp}[uml1](20,20)
Class.A("Point")
       ("+x: int",
        "+y: int") ();

Class.B("Circle")
       ("radius: int")
       ("+getRadius(): int",
        "+setRadius(r: int):void");

topToBottom(45)(A, B);

drawObjects(A, B);

link(aggregationUni)(A, B);
\end{emp}
\end{empfile}
\immediate\write18{mpost -tex=latex \jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A minimal example with the error message always helps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the emp documentation: "Required arguments are the width and the height of the figure, in units of `\unitlength` [...] `\begin{emp}[⟨name⟩](⟨width⟩,⟨height⟩)`"

So you need to write

```
\begin{emp}(100,100)
```

or whatever.