# metapost and pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, metapost

I'm trying to use figures created with metapost in a TeX document compiled with `pdflatex`, but I have some troubles. I did as advised [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5330/embedding-metapost-in-latex-document), but it fails!

My code is this :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}  
\usepackage{graphics}  
\begin{document}  
\includegraphics{figures/TryMetaPost.1}  
\end{document}
```

With plain `latex` I have no problem but with `pdflatex` I obtained:

```
LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .1
```

I tried also with `.mps` and in this case I have (with `pdflatex`)

```
Cannot convert figures/TryMetaPost1.mps from MPS to PDF
```

Does anybody see my mistake?

Comment: possible duplicate of [\includegraphics: Dots in filename](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/includegraphics-dots-in-filename)

Answer (score 8):

The first message simply means that pdfLaTeX doesn't know the extension. You can get around this problem either by changing the extension to `.mps` or by declaring a rule:

```
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.1}{mps}{*}{}
```

The second message is more problematic: It indicates that pdflatex has problems to convert the mps. Which means that either the mps itself is broken or something doesn't work in your system. Could you show the offending mps and the log-file?

Comment: I will search in this way. I think the problem comes from the fact that I have only version 0.993 of mpost. What do you think?

Comment: I will certainly not start to guess around without some more reliable informations. And if you have an old mpost everything else is probably old too. So don't look only in one direction.

Comment: The log file (metapost) LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.                                   
l.12 /
      bd{bind def}bind def/fshow {exch findfont exch scalefont setfont show}bd
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.12 /
      bd{bind def}bind def/fshow {exch findfont exch scalefont setfont show}bd

Comment: Don't send information snippets. Make a complete example, with a tex-file, the mp, the resulting mps and the complete log-file in a zip-file and put them somewhere for download.

Answer (score 6):

Adding `\DeclareGraphicsRule{.1}{mps}{*}{}` to a `tex` file works for `pdflatex`, which is OK with respect to the subject of this question.  But it has the side-effect of breaking `latex`, because `mps` is not a pre-defined file extension for `latex`.  To circumvent this, one should check for the actual TeX engine used, e.g.,

```
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi
```

---

The [MetaPost manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/metapost/base/manual/mpman.pdf) suggests another method, though.  Recent MetaPost versions have a file name template mechanism that can be used to change the format of MetaPost output file names.  Adding the line

```
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.mps";
```

to the preamble of a MetaPost input file named `figs.mp`, makes output files have names `figs-1.mps`, `figs-2.mps` etc.  Files ending `mps` can easily be included in LaTeX documents by giving the full name to `\includegraphics` like

```
\includegraphics{figs-1.mps}
```

This works with `latex` as well as `pdflatex` without messing with `\DeclareGraphicsRule`.  See the [MetaPost manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/metapost/base/manual/mpman.pdf) and Keith Reckdahl's [*Using Imported Graphics in LaTeX and pdfLaTeX*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/epslatex/english/epslatex.pdf) for why that works.